# Default value for datetime field definition in content entity?

Tags: 8, entities

I have the following datetime field definition for my content entity:

```
$fields['start_date'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('datetime')
  ->setLabel(t('Start date'))
  ->setDescription(t('Start date in GMT time.'))
  ->setSettings([
    'default_value' => DrupalDateTime::createFromTimestamp(time()),
  ])
  ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
    'label' => 'above',
    'type' => 'string',
    'weight' => -4,
  ])
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
    'type' => 'datetime_default',
    'weight' => -3,
  ])
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
```

As a result, when creating a new entity, I get the field display without default value set in a form. I also tried setDefaultValue method but with no luck.
What is the proper way to set the default values for the custom content entities?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to pass in a callback function that is evaluated when the entity is saved. If you evaluate the time value in `YourEntity::baseFieldDefinitions`, then the default value will fixed at whatever time the entity type was installed.

`DrupalDateTime::createFromTimestamp` can't serve as a callback because it expects you to pass a timestamp. The default value callback needs to take two arguments: the entity being saved and the field definition itself:

- `\Drupal\Core\Entity\FieldableEntityInterface $entity`
- `\Drupal\Core\Field\FieldDefinitionInterface $definition`

See the API docs: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21FieldConfigInterface.php/function/FieldConfigInterface%3A%3AsetDefaultValueCallback/8.7.x

So you'll need to create a callback function, e.g.

```
use Drupal\datetime\Plugin\Field\FieldType\DateTimeItem;

// ...

function mymodule_get_current_datetime($entity, $definition) {
  $current_time = DrupalDateTime::createFromTimestamp(time());
  return $current_time->format(DateTimeItem::DATETIME_STORAGE_FORMAT);
}
```

And then pass that callback as a string.

```
$fields['start_date'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('datetime')
  ->setLabel(t('Start date'))
  ->setDescription(t('Start date in GMT time.'))
  ->setDefaultValueCallback('mymodule_get_current_datetime')
  ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
    'label' => 'above',
    'type' => 'string',
    'weight' => -4,
  ])
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
    'type' => 'datetime_default',
    'weight' => -3,
    'default_value' => DrupalDateTime::createFromTimestamp(time()),
  ])
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
```

Answer (score 3):

Field of type `datetime` accept date with format `Y-m-d\TH:i:s` So to set the default value, the date should be in this format, try with the following.

```
// Get the current date time in the format Y-m-d\TH:i:s.
    $current_date_time = DrupalDateTime::createFromTimestamp(time())
      ->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s');
    $fields['start_date'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('datetime')
      ->setLabel(t('Start date'))
      ->setDescription(t('Start date in GMT time.'))
      ->setDefaultValue($current_date_time)
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
        'label' => 'above',
        'type' => 'string',
        'weight' => -4,
      ])
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
        'type' => 'datetime_default',
        'weight' => -3,
      ])
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on @berramou answer, I think this would be the right way (timezone and format wise):

```
->setDefaultValue(DrupalDateTime::createFromTimestamp(\Drupal::time()
      ->getRequestTime(), DateTimeItemInterface::STORAGE_TIMEZONE)
      ->format(DateTimeItemInterface::DATETIME_STORAGE_FORMAT))
```

Comment: I don't think this will work as this code will just run at the time the module gets installed so will still be a static date. Your saving a string, not a dynamic function.

Answer (score 1):

To add current datetime when create or update your values you should use:

```
BaseFieldDefinition::create('created')
BaseFieldDefinition::create('changed')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an array to the default value to use the current time the entity is being created.

```
$fields['start_date'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('datetime')
      ->setLabel(t('Start date'))
      ->setDescription(t('Start date in GMT time.'))
      ->setDefaultValue([
        'default_date_type' => 'now',
        'default_date'      => 'now',
      ])
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
        'label' => 'above',
        'type' => 'string',
        'weight' => -4,
      ])
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
        'type' => 'datetime_default',
        'weight' => -3,
      ])
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
```

The key bit of information here being:

```
[
    'default_date_type' => 'now',
    'default_date'      => 'now',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer of CallMarl, mentioning that you should use another data type instead, the actual proper way to initialize *any* data of your custom entity, including not only timestamps but anything else, is to use the `preCreate()` function, for instance:

```
public static function preCreate(EntityStorageInterface $storage, array &$values) {
  parent::preCreate($storage, $values);

  $values['user_id'] = \Drupal::currentUser()->id();
  $values['created'] = time();
  $values['uuid'] = \Drupal::service('uuid')->generate();
}
```