# Filling in default value for datetime field in custom entity

Tags: datetime

I am trying to set the default value for the date field in a custom Entity.
The code does not produce any errors. The date field does just not populate with any value. How can I set the default value?

[image]

```
   $fields['date'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('datetime')
      ->setLabel(t('Date'))
      ->setDescription(t('The date of the entity.'))
      ->setDefaultValue('2021-09-09')
  
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
        'label' => 'above',
        'weight' => -6,
      ])
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
        'weight' => -6,
      ])
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE)
      ->setRequired(TRUE);
```

Answer (score 1):

To fill default value for the date field, you have two options:

1. create a DrupalDateTime and set it as default value like the following:

```
  use Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime;
  use Drupal\datetime\Plugin\Field\FieldType\DateTimeItemInterface;

  $default_date = DrupalDateTime::createFromTimestamp(strtotime("2021-09-09"));
  $default_date = $default_date->format(DateTimeItemInterface::DATETIME_STORAGE_FORMAT);
 // set default value.
  ->setDefaultValue($default_date)
```

2. or this way

```
  ->setDefaultValue([
    'default_date_type' => 'custom',
    'default_date'      => '2021-09-09',
  ])
```

*Note :* if you want the default value to be dynamic take a look at this answer it's more complete [Default value for datetime field definition in content entity?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/284423/default-value-for-datetime-field-definition-in-content-entity#answer-284431)

Comment: Thank I tried both of your sultions. Both did not change anything. The field still displays no value (caches cleared multiple times) like in the screenshot above. I knew about your noted link before but even that did not work here. Any other ideas what I might be doing wrong or how to debug this?

Comment: where did you put the BaseFieldDefinition un the *hook_entity_base_field_info_alter* or in the entity class ?

Comment: I put it in the class.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by editing the form class if we want to have some dynamic defaults for the DateTime:

```php
use Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime;

final class FooForm extends ContentEntityForm {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function form(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form = parent::form($form, $form_state);

    // Set the date seven days from now.
    $form['foo_date']['widget'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = DrupalDateTime::createFromTimestamp(time() + 3600 * 24 * 7);

    return $form;
  }

// ...
}
```